# List of French minimal pairs

Tags: prononciation, ressources

I'm searching for a comprehensive list of minimal pairs in the French language. At best a list that contains minimal pairs for all possible combination of phonemes. Can you point me to a resource? It's okay if it's in French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pretergramaticaly created such a list, and detailed the process [on my blog](http://verbally.flimzy.com/list-of-french-minimal-pairs/). The list itself, which is quite long (2921 pairs!) can be seen [here](http://aslan.flimzy.com/~jonhall/french-pairs.html).

Answer (score 3):

Il est possible de générer cette liste en quelques étapes simples:

- étape 1: télécharger le Wiktionnaire français
- étape 2: faire une recherche par expression régulière (regexp) pour construire une association mot->prononciation
- étape 3 : (optionnelle) filtrer les prononciations pour vérifier qu'elles soient vraisemblables
- étape 4 : définir la notion de 'paire minimale' de manière concrète (elle doit opérer sur une chaîne de caractères, ce qui inclue de gérer les 'combining Unicode characters' pour l'Alphabet Phonétique International). 'Concrètement', quelle distance impose la nasalisation entre deux mots phonétiques.
- étape 5 : lancer un programme pas trop inefficace

Un exemple de sortie de ce programme, qui implémente 3 comme 'peut être généré par les règles de prononciation du français' et 4 comme 'distance de Levenshtein de 1 sur la représentation X-Sampa de la prononciation' donne au bout de 1 heure: https://github.com/rbbb/fr-minpair/blob/master/minPairs.zip .

A noter, ma distance n'est pas transitive et ne donne pas une classe d’équivalence (en français, c'est une définition mathématiquement pas pratique de paire minimale car aura <-> Laura par addition et Laura <-> Laurent par nasalisation, mais aura <-!!!-> Laurent). Une paire minimale est plutôt en général vue comme distance de Hamming de 1 qui ne sera pas transitive non plus.

Les prononciations du Wiktionnaire ne sont pas complètement normatives, surtout sur 300 000 mots.

On notera également l’utilité douteuse de 30Mo de paires 'minimales'. On sait désormais que remaillonnasses et remarronnasses forment une paire minimale...

Comment: exemple de prononciation non normalisée: décelés[desle] / décelé[des@le]

Answer (score 2):

Rien de vraiment satisfaisant mais un début en attendant mieux :

1. Sur [LanguageGuide](http://www.languageguide.org/), à la rubrique prononciation, on trouve un début de rapprochement en paires minimales de certains sons voyelles dans les deux listes proposées. [1](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/pronunciation/index.html) et [2](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/pronunciation/vowels2.html). Ainsi que dans la liste des [nasales](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/pronunciation/nasal.html).

   Par contre pas d'opposition sur les paires minimales en ce qui concerne les consonnes, et pourtant il y a tout un travail à faire avec les sons /f/ et /v/, /d/ et /t/, /b/ et /v/, /l/ / et /r/, …
2. Deux tableaux dans un article dans un blog destiné à des professeurs de FLE (Français langue Étrangère) qui sont peut-être trop touffus pour des apprenants, mais tu peux toujours regarder [cet article](http://phonetiquedufle.canalblog.com/archives/2014/04/10/29432822.html). Les deux tableaux sont :

   - Les paires minimales Consonne + Voyelle (CV)
   - Les paires minimales Consonne + Voyelle + Consonne (CVC)

Comment: Dans le tableau CVC, à [n] il n'y a que deux colonnes : est-ce *nasse, naisse, noce, Nantes, nonce, nef,* ne peuvent être candidats ?

Comment: @cl-r ça faudrait le demander à l'auteur. Par ailleurs je tiens à préciser qu'il y a très peu de travaux à ce sujet concernant le français, (au contraire de l'anglais par exemple) car l'enseignement du FLE a semble-t-il désinvesti de tout travail spécifique sur la prononciation (phonétique, intonation, rythme,...). L'enseignement des langues vivantes n'en est plus actuellement au modèle du natif, on met l'accent sur le minimum nécessaire pour que la communication "passe". Bien sûr les avis des spécialistes de la question sont très partagés et la polémique n'a pas sa place ici.

Comment: Bonjour, je suis l'auteur du blog (http://phonetiquedufle.canalblog.com/archives/2014/04/10/29432822.html) que vous mentionnez. Et je ne découvre qu'aujourd'hui vos messages... Merci de vos lectures attentives, remarques pertinentes et de vos suggestions que j'ai intégrées. J'en ai profité pour faire un certain nombre d'autres modifications. L'objectif de cette liste était à l'origine de proposer les paires minimales impliquées dans des confusions phonétiques en FLE, c'est-à-dire dans les séries [i-y-u], [e-ø-o / E-Œ-O], et [ɛ̃, ɑ̃, õ]. Merci encore et n'hésitez pas à me contacter via mon blo

Comment: @Lauret Le message que j'ai voulu laisser sur le blog n'a pas été validé, je l'ai mis sur http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette